# Trouble with window.read() function in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to get a simple GUI setup in Python, and am using PySimpleGUI to do this. When I copy and pasted the example code from their website, I got an error that the window.read() function is not iterable when destructuring it.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [[sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
          [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
          [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

(Here's a screenshot cause the error doesn't show up here)

[image]

It seems to print out an array, I just don'y know why this error is popping up. I'm new to python and GUI libraries so maybe I'm missing something?